# Unsuccessful TensorSliceReader constructor: Failed to find any matching files for ./model_save.\encoder_weights

Tags: python, tensorflow

I tried saving my model out and then tried to restore it, but seems tensor is unable to find the location of the matching files :-

Code to save model output :-

```
save_dir = './model_save.'
encoder_prefix = os.path.join(save_dir, "encoder_weights")
decoder_prefix = os.path.join(save_dir, "decoder_weights")

encoder.load_weights(encoder_prefix)
decoder.load_weights(decoder_prefix)

NotFoundError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[23], line 1
----> 1 encoder.load_weights(encoder_prefix)
      2 decoder.load_weights(decoder_prefix)

File c:\Users\foodi\anaconda3\envs\mt2\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py:67, in filter_traceback.<locals>.error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
     65 except Exception as e:  # pylint: disable=broad-except
     66   filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.__traceback__)
---> 67   raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
     68 finally:
     69   del filtered_tb

File c:\Users\foodi\anaconda3\envs\mt2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\py_checkpoint_reader.py:31, in error_translator(e)
     27 error_message = str(e)
     28 if 'not found in checkpoint' in error_message or (
     29     'Failed to find any '
     30     'matching files for') in error_message:
---> 31   raise errors_impl.NotFoundError(None, None, error_message)
     32 elif 'Sliced checkpoints are not supported' in error_message or (
     33     'Data type '
     34     'not '
     35     'supported') in error_message:
     36   raise errors_impl.UnimplementedError(None, None, error_message)

NotFoundError: Unsuccessful TensorSliceReader constructor: Failed to find any matching files for ./model_save.\encoder_weights
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to load weights from a path where the weights are not saved. You first need to save the weights in order to load them, it can be done either by creating a `tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint` callback that saves weights or by  manually saving the weights using `tf.keras.Model.save_weights`.

**1. Creating a `tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint` callback**

```
#Create checkpoint
checkpoint_path = ".model_save/cp.ckpt"
checkpoint_dir = os.path.dirname(checkpoint_path)

# Create a callback that saves the model's weights
cp_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(filepath=checkpoint_path,
                                                 save_weights_only=True,
                                                 verbose=1)
```

The above callback is then passed to the fit() like below

```
encoder.fit(x_train_noisy, x_train_noisy,
                epochs=10,
                batch_size=128,
                shuffle=True,callbacks=[cp_callback])
```

Then load weights with the following

```
encoder_weights=encoder.load_weights(".model_save/cp.ckpt")
```

**2. Saving the weights using `tf.keras.Model.save_weights` and loading them with `tf.keras.Model.load_weights`**

```
#Saving weights        
encoder.save_weights(encoder_prefix)
#Loading weights
loaded_weights=encoder.load_weights(encoder_prefix)
```

Please find the sample code [here](https://colab.sandbox.google.com/gist/synandi/b55b1a094d44a5c6765609f8657aa125/74844622.ipynb#scrollTo=gltXkewhAdJm). Thank you!

Comment: Thanks a lot I want save and download model file after train EPOCH can you help me and edit my code  and add save and download code after EPOCH

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1YDq5u6AbAzZw6dnurFaoZCgbIJKt2-UR?usp=share_link